# Make create-react-app available to computers outside of local network

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, hosting, create-react-app

I was hoping to run my react-app and make it accessible to computers outside of my local network. I want someone to be able to type in :3000 (or other secure port) and be able to see my application. Is this possible without using a hosting service like Netlify? Obviously there are security concerns but this is primarily for out of network testing for a video player I'm creating.

Thank you.

Comment: are you using express js or just create-react-app by default?

Comment: Just create-react-app

Comment: you will need to open your 3000 port to public (via modem and firewall config) and then they can access it with your WAN IP plus port

Answer (score 1):

Simply run `HOST=0.0.0.0 npm run start`.
Afterwards open the url from another device on the network.

Find whatever your ip is through `ipconfig` on cmd in windows and then 
for e.g
replace this ip with what your ip is:
192.153.23.10:3000 would work.

Further read : [Docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/docusaurus/docs/advanced-configuration.md)

there is also a great service called [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)which can assign https secure address to localhost apps. I know how to make it work with express and next js but there would be something for you there too check it out.